# Using Application Insights for applications in Enterprise network infrastructure

Tags: azure, windows-runtime, azure-application-insights

I have Enterprise application (WinRT 8.1 app for tablets), that used in Enterprise network with strong security configuration. It means that direct access to internet does not always exists.

But users sometimes have any problems with performance or crashes. I would like to use Application Insights for other monitorings and analisys in app.

How I can use it in Enterprise environment?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/668463b2-7712-43b4-8ace-120d30e25346/using-application-insights-for-applications-in-enterprise-infrastructure-and-network?forum=ApplicationInsights

Comment: The next problem is that currently the AI backend will reject any data that is more than 48 hours old.  so even if you do hold it, if you don't send it within 48 hours, it would be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Application Insights Persistence Channel - designed for apps that run where the internet connection is not always available or slow. See details at [Application Insights on Windows Desktop apps, services and worker roles - Persistence Channel](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-desktop/#persistence-channel).

Comment: This will work, in a limited manner. The AI backend will reject any data that is more than 48 hours old.  so even if you do hold it, if you don't send it within 48 hours, it will be rejected and it is just as gone.